# Can anyone identify this Xenoverse 2 character?

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse-2

I came across an interesting voice in the Xenoverse 2 files yesterday. What's the name of this character and what's his story in the DBZ universe? Where do you fight him in Xenoverse 2? I played the game a few times but I don't remember hearing this guy. Voice clip: http://vocaroo.com/i/s1CESptJ2hFK

Edit: Listening to the clip again I think this voice might belong to the smallest android, the one who fought Vegeta while Goku fought Android 13 in the movie. But he isn't in Xenoverse 2 as far as I know.

Comment: You could always look up the voice actors for the game and compare their voices to that clip if you were really determined.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, he isn't in the game. The only androids in the game (so far) are 13,16,17,Super 17,18 and Cell.